# How to vectorize a function having ndarray of different shape as an argument?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, vectorization

I have the following function:

```
def reshape_to_array(in_dict, pattern):
    vec_func = np.frompyfunc(in_dict.get, 1, 1)
    return vec_func(pattern)
func = np.frompyfunc(reshape_to_array,2,1)
```

Input:

```
dump = np.array([[{'HH': 'a00', 'HV': 'b00', 'VH': 'c00', 'VV': 'd00'},
        {'HH': 'a01', 'HV': 'b01', 'VH': 'c01', 'VV': 'd01'},
        {'HH': 'a02', 'HV': 'b02', 'VH': 'c02', 'VV': 'd02'},
        {'HH': 'a03', 'HV': 'b03', 'VH': 'c03', 'VV': 'd03'}],
       [{'HH': 'a10', 'HV': 'b10', 'VH': 'c10', 'VV': 'd10'},
        {'HH': 'a11', 'HV': 'b11', 'VH': 'c11', 'VV': 'd11'},
        {'HH': 'a02', 'HV': 'b02', 'VH': 'c02', 'VV': 'd02'},
        {'HH': 'a13', 'HV': 'b13', 'VH': 'c13', 'VV': 'd13'}],
       [{'HH': 'a20', 'HV': 'b20', 'VH': 'c20', 'VV': 'd20'},
        {'HH': 'a21', 'HV': 'b21', 'VH': 'c21', 'VV': 'd21'},
        {'HH': 'a22', 'HV': 'b22', 'VH': 'c22', 'VV': 'd22'},
        {'HH': 'a23', 'HV': 'b23', 'VH': 'c23', 'VV': 'd23'}],
       [{'HH': 'a30', 'HV': 'b30', 'VH': 'c30', 'VV': 'd30'},
        {'HH': 'a31', 'HV': 'b31', 'VH': 'c31', 'VV': 'd31'},
        {'HH': 'a32', 'HV': 'b32', 'VH': 'c32', 'VV': 'd32'},
        {'HH': 'a33', 'HV': 'b33', 'VH': 'c33', 'VV': 'd33'}]])

pattern = np.array([['HH', 'HV'], ['VH', 'VV']])
```

When I execute:

```
x = func(dump, pattern)
```

It throws ryuntime error:

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (4,4) (2,2)
```

But if I modify the `reshape_to_array` function in the following way:

```
# pattern is global
pattern = np.array([['HH', 'HV'], ['VH', 'VV']])
def reshape_to_array(in_dict):
    vec_func = np.frompyfunc(in_dict.get, 1, 1)
    return vec_func(pattern)
func = np.frompyfunc(reshape_to_array,1,1)
```

And execute `func(dump)` it executes successfully and returns the expected (correct) output. Which is:

```
x = np.array([[array([['a00', 'b00'],
       ['c00', 'd00']]),
        array([['a01', 'b01'],
       ['c01', 'd01']]),
        array([['a02', 'b02'],
       ['c02', 'd02']]),
        array([['a03', 'b03'],
       ['c03', 'd03']])],
       [array([['a10', 'b10'],
       ['c10', 'd10']]),
        array([['a11', 'b11'],
       ['c11', 'd11']]),
        array([['a02', 'b02'],
       ['c02', 'd02']]),
        array([['a13', 'b13'],
       ['c13', 'd13']])],
       [array([['a20', 'b20'],
       ['c20', 'd20']]),
        array([['a21', 'b21'],
       ['c21', 'd21']]),
        array([['a22', 'b22'],
       ['c22', 'd22']]),
        array([['a23', 'b23'],
       ['c23', 'd23']])],
       [array([['a30', 'b30'],
       ['c30', 'd30']]),
        array([['a31', 'b31'],
       ['c31', 'd31']]),
        array([['a32', 'b32'],
       ['c32', 'd32']]),
        array([['a33', 'b33'],
       ['c33', 'd33']])]])
```

My questions are:

1. Why the function does not work in the first case but works fine in the second case?
2. How to overcome this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first `func` takes 2 inputs, which are broadcast against each other, and element tuples are passed to `reshape_to_array`

`dump` is (4,4), `pattern` is (2,2).  The error says that it can pair up the 2 - which should be obvious if you understand broadcasting.

If you reduce `dump` to (2,2) (or (2,1) or (1,2)) it should work.  So would a `pattern` that is (1,4) or (4,1).

---

In the 2nd case, the outer `frompyfunc` is passing each of the (4,4) `dump` elements to `reshape_to_array`. and `(4,4)` pattern is evaluated.

I suspect `x = func(dump[:,:,np.newaxis, np.newaxis], pattern)` would work, generating the same values but in a (4,4,2,2) array.  With different `np.newaxis` arangements we could produce (4,2,4,2) etc.

### broadcasting dict and pattern

```
In [291]: fn = lambda in_dict, pattern: in_dict.get(pattern)
In [299]: fn1 = np.frompyfunc(fn,2,1)
```

With a (4,4) `dump`, I can use a (1,4) `pattern` (or a (4,1)):

```
In [300]: fn1(dump, pattern.reshape(1,4))
Out[300]: 
array([['a00', 'b01', 'c02', 'd03'],
       ['a10', 'b11', 'c02', 'd13'],
       ['a20', 'b21', 'c22', 'd23'],
       ['a30', 'b31', 'c32', 'd33']], dtype=object)
```

If I add `newaxis` to `dump` I can get a (4,4,2,2) array:

```
In [302]: fn1(dump[:,:,None,None], pattern)
Out[302]: 
array([[[['a00', 'b00'],
         ['c00', 'd00']],

        [['a01', 'b01'],
         ['c01', 'd01']],

        [['a02', 'b02'],
         ['c02', 'd02']],

         ....

        [['a32', 'b32'],
         ['c32', 'd32']],

        [['a33', 'b33'],
         ['c33', 'd33']]]], dtype=object)
In [303]: _.shape
Out[303]: (4, 4, 2, 2)
```

These are the same as your `x`, except without the (4,4) (2,2) nesting.

If I copy-n-paste your `x`, which produces a (4,4,2,2) 'U3' array (it doesn't preserve the nesting), and compare:

```
In [309]: np.all(xx == Out[302].astype('U3'))
Out[309]: True
```

### wrapped pattern

You can wrap your last version in a function definition:

```
def foo(pattern):
    def reshape_to_array(in_dict):
        vec_func = np.frompyfunc(in_dict.get, 1, 1)
        return vec_func(pattern)
    func = np.frompyfunc(reshape_to_array,1,1)
    return func
```

Which will be used as:

```
In [313]: foo(pattern)
Out[313]: <ufunc '? (vectorized)'>
In [314]: foo(pattern)(dump)
# your x
```

### outer vectorize

```
In [334]: def reshape_to_array(in_dict, pattern=None):
     ...:     vec_func = np.frompyfunc(in_dict.get, 1, 1)
     ...:     return vec_func(pattern)

In [335]: f = np.vectorize(reshape_to_array, excluded=['pattern'], otypes=['O'])
In [336]: f(dump, pattern=pattern)
```

### vectorize with complex otypes

```
In [380]: def reshape_to_array1(in_dict, pattern=None):
     ...:     vec_func = np.vectorize(in_dict.get, otypes=[complex])
     ...:     return vec_func(pattern)
     ...: 
     ...: 
In [381]: f = np.vectorize(reshape_to_array1, excluded=['pattern'], otypes=['O
     ...: '])
In [382]: dd = np.array([{'HH': 1+j, 'HV': 1j, 'VH':2j, 'VV': 1+2j}])
In [383]: f(dd, pattern=pattern)
Out[383]: 
array([array([[3.+0.j, 0.+1.j],
       [0.+2.j, 1.+2.j]])], dtype=object)
```

Comment: I understand your point. What I actually need is the result of the second function but without hard coding the pattern. Also I need this generalization because the shape of pattern may not be always 2x2.

Comment: `np.vectorize` uses `np.frompyfunc`, and allows you to `exclude` certain arguments from 'vectorization'  - I think it passes those arguments through a cover function.

Comment: Do you mean `func = np.vectorize(reshape_to_array, excluded=["pattern"])` ? I tried this just now, throws the same runtime error.

Comment: The last one is the easiest solution. It did not occur to me that in the function call itself it should be specified as pattern=pattern. It seems logical as it is excluded in vectorize and python function arguments are not ordered. Thank you.

Comment: I tried to replace `vec_func = np.frompyfunc(in_dict.get, 1, 1)` to `vec_func = np.vectorize(in_dict.get)` so that correct `dtype` is returned instead of `object`. But that does not work and throws runtime error stating `TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars`. This is strange because `vectorize` is basically a wrapper for `frompyfunc`.

Comment: In my last example I specified `otypes`.

Comment: Yes. In this case it only works with `otypes=['O']`. If all the values of the dictionary is lets say `complex` then each element of the array should be an array of `dtype=complex`.When I pass `otypes=[complex]` it gives runtime error as stated above.

Comment: When I use plain `vectorize` in `In[334]` I get `U3` arrays.  The object otypes is needed in the outer `vectorize` since `reshape_to_array` returns an array.  `frompyfunc` returns object dtype; a big part of the `vectorize` wrapper is converting that object to something more conventional (deduced or `otypes`).

Comment: Strange. In my computer plain vectorize in the inside does not work. It throws: `TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars`

Comment: I'm using your `dump` example where the dictionary values are strings. If you don't specify `otypes`, `vectorize` tries to deduce the return `dtype` from a test calc.  If it can't deduce that correctly you need specify `otypes`.

Comment: I am working with `complex` number instead of `strings`. I tried to specify `otypes=[complex]`. It shows runtime error.